# Events ID 4013 For DNS and 1844 for Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I  have newly registered a virtual private server (windows 2008 R2).  My problem is when i install an Active Directory and DNS Roles, it raises events 4013 for DNS and 1844 for Active Directory.  What i understand from errors that the DNS cant start before the active directory finishes synchronization.  Can anyone help me ?

Comment: How many domain controllers are in the domain?

Comment: Just one, the one that i use it